# Automatically import object from parent class

Tags: typescript

right now I am exporting a "singleton" `WebGL2RenderingContext` as follows:

```
export default GLHelper.GetGLContext(UIHelper.Canvas);
```

After that I am using it throughout the entire application like:

```
import gl from '.';

gl.DrawElements(/*...*/);
```

My Project structure has its root in a `app.ts` class. Inside this class I have instances of other classes and basically every class uses the above export.

My problem is that once I decide to use several canvas elements I will have multiple `WebGL2RenderingContext` objects, thus my singleton export would always operate on the same canvas.

The only solution for this case I can think of is to get all context objects and pass them down as parameter throughout the entire code. I am thinking of something like:

```
const ctx1 = GLHelper.GetGLContext("id1");
const ctx2 = GLHelper.GetGLContext("id2");

const app1 = new App(ctx1);
const app2 = new App(ctx2);
```

In the `App` class I would have to further pass down the object like:

```
class App {

    private _ctx: WebGL2RenderingContext;

    constructor (ctx: WebGL2RenderingContext) {
        this._ctx = ctx;
        // Pass down the context
        const renderingObj = new Mesh(ctx);
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is a single export in the `App` class which automatically will be used in the other classes simply by importing it. That way I would like the `renderingObj` to automatically use the context which was exported in the `App` instance that it was created in. All this would really be cool if I would not to have to pass down the context as parameter.

Is there a way to achieve this or maybe to solve the problem in another way?

Answer (score 2):

Umm not sure but I think You can create global variables and then use it everywhere you need.

Example for creating global variable.

```
// First declare the window global outside the class

declare let window: any;

// Inside the required class method

let globVarName = window.globVarName;
```

EDIT:

> What I would like to achieve is a single export in the App class which
>   automatically will be used in the other classes simply by importing
>   it.

One option is to use global variable in App class to declare it once and use it everywhere, rather than passing down the context as parameter individually in every case.

Comment: Please elaborate how this solution would work in the above scenario. Otherwise this answer ist fishing for last minute bounty!

Comment: @チーズパン is this helped you or not?

Comment: Nah not really so far. But that just might be me. I will accept as soon as I can verify.